# Record video and audio from an X windows application

Tags: x11, ffmpeg

I want to script the following scenario, from a server which I access using SSH.

1. Create a screen at an arbitrary resolution, for example 1280x720.
2. Start an application, that will fill this entire screen, for example Firefox.
3. Record both audio and video, using ffmpeg or a similar tool.

The recording should stop when I send a signal (sighup?) to a process.

I want to be able to do several sessions like this simultaneously, if the server can handle it.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: some keywords to search for: Xvfb, screencast